# How to know body is in rest in Libdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I just want to remove the bodies when they come to state of rest from motion?i have tried using body.isAwake()

```
if (TimeUtils.millis()-lastDropTime>1000) dropBall();//creating new body every 1 sec
          //iterate over all the bodies
        Iterator<Body> iterator = ballBodies.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           Body body = iterator.next();
          if(body.isAwake()==false){
              world.destroyBody(body);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

but this is not working

Comment: Did you enable your bodies to be able to sleep? Another reason could be that your bodies never come to complete rest. You could check the bodies Speed and delete them if they pass a certain thresold. Like that: 
if (Body.getLinearVelocity().len() < 0.2f) { ...delete }

Comment: yes,it works, actually when body is falling from above its initial velocity is zero, so i add this condition to work fully     if (body.getPosition().y*PIXELS_TO_METERS<110&&body.getLinearVelocity().len()<0.2f). thanks for your help

Comment: one more thing,becoz some bodies are rotating, they never removed,i tried  different values and also add this condition  body.getAngularVelocity()<0.4f, but i could not make it perfect, any suggestion